# Why does the ";" exist when it goes against formatting standards?

Tags: python, python-2.7

As you know, the `;` symbol is used to separate lines like this:

```
print "Hai"; print "Bai"
```

From what I've heard, this goes against formatting standards for python. So, if this goes against formatting standards, why was it implemented? How is it used properly?

Comment: It can come in handy when executing a simple chain of statements from the command line with `python -c`.

Comment: Handy when using `timeit` in particular.

Comment: Formatting standards are rarely enforced quite enough to make syntactical conveniences go away entirely. Why is the tab character still allowed to be used for indentation since it would violate PEP 8 to use it for such?

Comment: I was going to tag this question with [tag:java] just to mess with everyone, but that wouldn't be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

";" are used in cases, you have no other choice. E.g. when calling Python from command line and willing to execute those two statements.

```
$ python -c "print 'Hai'; print 'Bai'"
Hai
Bai
```

Or more complex cases:

```
$ python -c 'a=1; b=2; print "a + b = {a} + {b} = {res}".format(a=a, b=b, res=a+b)'
a + b = 1 + 2 = 3
```

note: Do not take my "no other choice" literally, you will find nice alternatives to some cases in comments.

Comment: Actually, you have another choice, using `python -c "exec(\"foo\\nbar\")"`

Comment: @user667648 Do as you like. But your `timeit` note is worth a note anyway, anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

To extend on Jan Vlcinsky's answer, if you're trying to quickly determine the efficiency of something, `timeit` comes in handy. For example, ([from the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#examples)):

```
python -m timeit -s 'text = "sample string"; char = "g"'  'char in text'
```

Comment: Why don't you add it to the answer of Jan?

Comment: Bah, this can be written without semicolons! `python -m timeit -s 'text, char = "sample string", "g"' 'char in text'`

Comment: @user667648 I'm really just teasing. For one-offs, especially the `setup` argument to `timeit`, it really doesn't matter. Still, maybe knowing about tuple unpacking is useful for some passerby.

Comment: @ChristianBerendt This answer shows a case, which I did not know about and which I like. user667648 definitely deserves his upvotes.